# Grails Methods do not appear in Intellij Structure Pane

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I have some grails methods (example below) in Intellij Idea 12.  However, they do not show up in the Structure pane (Alt-7).  Only the methods defined in the typical Java style appear.

I have tried the various options ("Show non-public") on the tab bar, but nothing seems to get them to show up.

What could I be missing?  I have a large controller with a lot of methods that I am maintaining, and I like having a list of methods available to me.

Thanks.

```
def showLoginOptions =
{
    log.debug("in showLoginOptions")
    forward(action: "defaultLoginOptions")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `showLoginOptions` will never show up in a list of methods because it is not a method, it's a *field* (well, it technically compiles to a Java Bean property - a private field plus public methods `getShowLoginOptions` and `setShowLoginOptions`) whose initial value is a closure.